# php catching dependent library exception correctly

Tags: php, exception, doctrine-orm

Hello everybody I have a problem with exception.

The following code block do this result:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException' with message 'Could not convert database value .....
```

Code:

```
foreach ($result as $indexArray => $objectID) {
  try {
    $tempObject = new OggettoEbayDB();
    $tempObject = $entityManager->find('OggettoEbayDB',$objectID);
    if($tempObject->checkValid()){
    //.... do something else      
    }    
  } catch(Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException $e){
    $arrayOggettoEbayDBDeleted [] = '<b>Oggetto con id -> '.$tempObject->getId().' ha dato problemi con il seguente messaggio '.$e->getMessage().'<br/><br/>';
  }
}
```

I need as may be obvious to catch the object with the error first but continue the foreach on other object later

I am anyway not able to go in the catch block, the exception is always catched as " uncaught "

have I to specify the correct type or what?

Thanks anybuddy!

Comment: Does it work with `catch (Exception $e)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to namespace resolution rules.

When you're not in the Doctrine namespace itself, you should make the exception class absolute by prefixing it with a backslash:

```
\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException
```

Answer (score 1):

The code block You have provided is throwing an exception of other type that You are catching. Then You are trying to convert this exception into `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException` that throws new exception that is not catched anymore.

Try this first:

```
...
try { ... }
catch(\Exception $e) {
    $arrayOggettoEbayDBDeleted [] = '<b>Oggetto con id -> '.$tempObject->getId().' ha dato problemi con il seguente messaggio '.$e->getMessage().'<br/><br/>';
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Yes it works but I need to catch that exception. Thanks for your help